# Error with pagination

Tags: sql, debugging, sqlite, pagination

I get this error when I try to set up pagination for the elements in a feed:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Videos#feed_display

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/feed_display.html.erb where line #6 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression: SELECT  "timeline_events".* FROM "timeline_events" WHERE (SELECT timeline_events.* FROM timeline_events
                                       WHERE ((actor_type = 'User' AND actor_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = 2)) AND ((secondary_subject_type = 'Video' AND subject_type <> 'Profile' AND secondary_subject_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM videos WHERE user_id = 2)) OR (secondary_subject_type = 'User' AND secondary_subject_id <> 2) OR (secondary_subject_type = 'nil') OR (subject_type = 'Profile' AND secondary_subject_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM videos WHERE user_id = 2) AND subject_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM profiles WHERE user_id = 2))))
                                       ORDER BY timeline_events.created_at DESC) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your subquery is returning more than one column

Comment: what do you mean? how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the sub-queries returns more than one result.  This can be fixed by adding Distinct or a limit 1 to the sub-query.  I would use the firefox addon "Sqlite Manager" to test this query.

Comment: yeah, anywhere I have a SELECT in the WHERE clause returns more than one record because I am testing to see if something is inside of that range. If I limited the range to just one record, then the SQL code would not work as desired.